# how to create tags with characters in a text editor

Tags: javascript, tags, google-plus, text-editor

I was wondering how I can do to replace characters within a text with javascript.

example:
Google is a *search engine*.

result:
Google is a **search engine**.

sites like Google+ do it in posts. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to find the text within * and then format it as you like. As basic JavaScript example:

```
var str = "Google is a *search engine*"; 
var patt1 = /\*.*\*/;
var temp = str.match(patt1)[0];
var new_str = '<strong>' + temp.substring( 1, temp.length - 1 ) + '</strong>';
console.log( str.replace( temp, new_str ) );
```

The code takes a string, finds text with asterisks and then updated original with the text in between asterisks in bold.

Produces:

```
Google is a <strong>search engine</strong>
```